# How to exclude particular class from a jar in gradle

Tags: gradle, spring-boot, dependencies

I want to exclude particular class from a jar in gradle dependency

```
dependencies {
    compile("com.example:myapp") {
        exclude("org/springframework/**")
    }
}
```

Any suggestions? I am stuck with the dirty class.

Comment: Is your problem that a dependency you use has foreign classes packed in their JAR, or what is your use-case?

Comment: You can exclude transitive dependencies, but not classes/packages from inside a dependency. Why are you "stuck with a dirty class" ? You're not required to use it even if you use a dependency that contains that class..

Answer (score 5):

You can unzip a jar using the `Copy` task, exclude the desired class and then add a file dependency on the extracted classes.

For example:

```
task unzipJar(type: Copy) {
   from zipTree('commons-collections-3.2.jar')
   into ("$buildDir/libs/commons-collection")
   include "**/*.class"
   exclude "**/Unmodifiable.class"
}

dependencies {
   compile files("$buildDir/libs/commons-collection") {
      builtBy "unzipJar"
   }
}
```