# Is there a way to exclude java classes from jar dependency?

Tags: java, gradle, dependencies

It' a pretty strange problem.
I have a 3rd party jar dependency published in inhouse artifactory. let's name it `irresistibility.jar` irresistibility.jar jar is fat: it contains some useful classes + `com.mycompany.anotherstuff.*`

`com.mycompany.anotherstuff.*` is included into irresistibility.jar fat jar during build and it conflicts with `anotherstuff.jar` which is also dependency and has up to date `com.mycompany.anotherstuff.*`

irresistibility.jar and anotherstuff.jar clash in runtime and sometimes outdated classes `com.mycompany.anotherstuff.*` from irresistibility.jar take over and all goes really bad.

I have NO chance to change irresistibility.jar build. It's just exist. I have no chance to rebuild from sources, it will take the rest of my life (legacy, you know).

Is there any viable option to:

- exclude classes `com.mycompany.anotherstuff.*` from irresistibility.jar using gradle when I add irresistibility.jar as dependency
- do some sort of hack and unzip irresistibility.jar, delete `com.mycompany.anotherstuff.*` and republish irresistibility.jar as irresistibility-good-stuff.jar without conflicting classes?

Comment: you can't [really](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40883974/gradle-exclude-a-dependencys-package).

Comment: You can try downloading the JAR manually and filtering only what is needed, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36473673/how-to-exclude-particular-class-from-a-jar-in-gradle) answer.